# jquery .ajax (or .eval) problem in IE

Tags: jquery, json, object, eval

Hopefully someone can shed some light onto this issue for me.

I have a little APP (http://www.bentinckfencing.co.uk/fence_calculator.php)

I have a php file that sends a JSON encoded string back.

Im using `jQuery` to retrieve this string with the `.ajax()` function. After I have the JSON string, I am then using `eval()` in this manner

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax-test.php",
   cache: false,
   data: "choice=34",
   success: function(data){

       var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');

       //Now I set lots of variables in this manner and use them later in the script

       var productName  = myObject[0]['name'];
       var productPrice = myObject[0]['price'];                                     
       var productID    = myObject[0]['id'];

        }
   });
```

As always, this works well in all browsers except IE which is throwing the error `object doesn't support this property or method`

I just can't think where I'm going wrong.. If anyone has time to help, or even to check out my app, I'm be most helpful :)

`edit`
I've found that the Ajax call is successfully retrieving the data in IE. It's string like this `[{"name":" 12 inch Rock Face Gravel Board","ID":"106","price":"7.00"},{"name":" 12 inch Double Sided Gravel Board","ID":"108","price":"10.50"},{"name":" 12 inch Smooth Gravel Boards","ID":"109","price":"7.00"}]`

So now my issue is down to how I handle the data now that JS has it... Any ideas would be great :)

Comment: Any reason not to use `dataType: "JSON"`?

Comment: I don't recommend you use `eval` ever. If there is another way, then consider it.

Comment: @JCOC611 I've tried using `var myObject = jQuery.parseJSON(stringFromPHP);` and also added the dataType: "JSON"... Same issue

Comment: What happens if you do `alert(data);`?

Comment: @patrick Ah! It shows me the entire JSON string...

Comment: Could you post that string (or a portion of it) in your question?

Comment: @patrick so the .ajax call is working.. This narrows it down to how I handle the string now it lies in JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `eval`, it's evil. Also make sure your server sends proper content type (application/json):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax-test.php',
    cache: false,
    data: { choice: 34 },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(items) {
        // TODO: some range checking on this array won't be useless
        // before trying to access its elements

        var productName = items[0].name;
        var productPrice = item[0].price;
        var productID = items[0].ID;

        // TODO: do something useful with those variables
    }
});
```

Also you probably don't need `cache: false` with a POST request. Those are probably reflexes that you got from IE and GET requests :-)

Comment: That doesn't fix the `object doesn't support this property or method` error.

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that my JSON array that get returned is a multi-dimensional array and I need to assign different variables to each item in the nested arrays...

Comment: @shane, great, then `items[0].name` and `items[0].ID` should work fine for you. And your JSON array is not a multidimentional array, at least the string you have shown in your question is not. It's a one dimensional array containing 3 items (ID: 106, ID: 108 and ID: 109).

Comment: I currently use this format to set variables to each item `product1 = myobject[0]['name'] product2 = myobject[1]['name']` etc, and the same for the prices & IDs.. Not sure how I can do that using the .each() loop.. :S

Comment: @shane, you said you didn't want an each loop.

Comment: Just noticed you've changed your answer... I'll try that method now. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @shane, yeah, I often change my answers based on the OP's comments and requirements.

Comment: @shane, and could you be a little more specific. For example telling why this didn't solve your issue?

Comment: @Darin When I used the code you kindly provided in your answer, I'm still getting my original error message from IE but not in any other browser..

Comment: @Darin Thanks for your help Darin, I feel rather silly now as I've just discovered my error... In a separate function I was declaring a `variable` without using the `var` keyword. This never threw an error in other browsers...  Anyway, I'm now using your method as stated in your answer as opposed to the `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
   var productID    = myObject[0]['id'];
```

should be:

```
   var productID    = myObject[0]['ID'];
```

Javascript identifiers are case sensitive.